Counting points on line in QGIS
In QGIS, I have a polygon layer representing substations. Rooting from these substations, there are a lot of line features leaving the substations representing power lines. On top of the power line layer, there is a point layer representing power towers along these lines at random distances. How can I add an attribute to the point layer(power towers) that counts the towers?

Use this expression:
array_find (
    array_sort( 
        array_agg( 
            line_locate_point( 
                overlay_nearest('line', @geometry)[0],
                @geometry               
            ),
            group_by:=overlay_nearest('line', @id)[0]
        )
    ),
    line_locate_point( 
        overlay_nearest('line', @geometry)[0],
        @geometry
    )
)+1

It uses the function line_locate_point() (to get the distance along the line from the start point to the point closest to the current feature - here, grouped according to the closest line), collects all these distances values in an array with array_agg(), sorts this array with array_sort() and then gets the index (position) the current point has in this array with array_find(). overlay_nearest() is used to get the closest linestring from each point.
The expression used to create a dynamic label:


That's a straight forward solution and works most of the time. However, there is a flaw with this approach for my data. Sometimes the line starts and ends in a substation. The towers with a number between 2 and 5 leaving each substation are of relevance for my analysis. Any idea how to deal with that? https://ibb.co/zb42Q39

Based on the screenshot, I don't see why you have numbers 56-58 instead of 2 to 4, probably because of the line direction. You could create a new vector line layer, a copy of your lines, and reverse line direction, split/merge the lines etc. according to your needs. Be awayre to copy the features to a new layer, don't create a duplicate of the layer, as any change would affect the initial data. Make a backup before.

Good idea! Changing the line direction and calculating the tower number a second time with the inverted line layer eleminates that problem compeltely. The towers are numbered 56-58 because  the numbering starts at an other substation which is located off screen. But your approach takes care of that (when a line runs between to substations). The last problem is that the tower count is resettet at the breakpoint of a line  if it consists of more then one feature.

For the last problem, merge those lines that should have a continuing numbering

One last problem remains. Even if a powerline does not start in a substation it is numbered accordingly. Any idea how to tackle this problem?https://ibb.co/XjVTfhY

In the auxiliary layer where you reverse direction and merge/split lines, delete those parts you don't want to use for numbering

Any idea on how to automate that step? There are several thousand line features in my dataset. So for example selecting all line features that start within or where the starting point touches the substation layer, invert selection and delete the now selected features.

Use select by expression: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-expression or select by location: https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#select-by-location

You can use this expression on your line layer:
array_length(overlay_nearest('powelineslayername', @id, max_distance:=<maximum distance>))

Preferably both layers are in the same CRS. The maximum distance from the line to the points is measured in CRS units. In case you are absolutely sure points and lines do intersect including tolerances you could also use overlay_intersect() instead.

I think I didn't find the right words. The attribute value should correspond to the number indicating which tower it is in sequence from the substation.
